# Negative feedback capacitor in Op-Amp comparator circuit

Tags: comparator

This is a part of a circuit of a big device. I'm interesting why need for C1 capacitor? OA2 is a general purpose opamp. Power supply for the opamp is +15V/-15V, sorry for mistakes in the picture.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw7ZIb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It looks like an integrator to slow down the output. What are the values of the resistors and the spec for the photodiode?

Comment: Who told you that you "need" the capacitor?

Comment: LvW: Nobody. This is a part of real circuit of a real device. I asked why developer add C1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a typical use of a **conventional Operational Amplifier working as a Comparator**.

Lets's first describe it intuitively:

- **If we left C1 out of the circuit (disconnected)**, we have an Op-Amp with no feedback (negative or positive). Under this condition, the output of the amplifier will be the difference of its inputs multiplied by the open loop gain.
- So, as soon as the **positive input becomes a little bit more positive that the negative input** (plus minus the input offset voltage error), **the output of the amplifier will "saturate" towards the positive power rail (+15V)**.
- On the other hand, **when the positive input has a voltage slightly lower that the voltage at the negative input**, **the output of the amplifier will "saturate" towards the negative rail (node 3)**.
- As the negative input is set by a simple resistor voltage divider and the positive input is the voltage generated on R2 by the current of the photodiode, this circuit is a **simple light intensity detector/discriminator**,

  1. The comparator threshold can be "programmed" by setting the ratio \$\frac{R4}{R3+R4}\$.
  2. The photodiode gain factor (transimpedance) is set by R2 alone.
- However, **the big question is what happens when/if the positive input stays close to the threshold voltage set at the negative input**. *What happens if the input signal of the photodiode (at R2) is noisy?*

  - The answer is that you will get a series of fast pulses at the output, swinging rail to rail. Not a good thing if you want to get a clean output signal.
  - Or the Op-Amp may start oscillating due to the fact that the high frequency gain of the circuit is unbounded.

Now, let's do the math and see how a simple low value capacitor used as negative feedback element can improve greatly our circuit:

- The gain of a non-inverting single Op-Amp circuit is given by: \$H(s)=1+\frac{Z_2}{Z_1}\$, where \$Z_2\$ is the feedback impedance (in our case, the capacitor), and \$Z_1\$ the equivalent paralell combination of \$R_3\$ and \$R_4\$, which we will call \$R_p\$.

  \$H(s)=1+\frac{Z_2}{Z_1} = 1+\frac{1}{R_p Cs} = \frac{R_pCs + 1}{R_pCs}  \$
- **The gain at DC (*zero frequency*)**, according to the previous expression, **will go up** to "infinite". In reality, the DC gain will be limited by the open-loop gain of the Op-Amp, **typically about >100000**.

  - So, *our circuit is still working as a comparator*, as its low frequency gain is huge.
- Note that **as you increase the frequency**, **the gains starts decreasing**, **until it becomes one at very high frequencies**.

  - This is great, as *now our circuit will become less sensitive to high frequency noise when the input is near its threshold*.

**In summary**,

> - **Adding a small feedback capacitor** to an Op-Amp working as a comparator, **will decrease the high frequency gain of the circuit,
>     making it more stable**. *This is mandatory for any Op-Amp working as a
>     comparator*, as many/most Op-Amps may oscillate if the high frequency
>     of the circuit is unbounded.
> - However, with the simple circuit shown above *you will still have some unwanted swinging at the ouput*, in case the noise is very high
>     and the input signal stays close to the threshold for "long" period of
>     time. In order **to increase the robustness of the circuit in that
>     situations, you need to add a little bit of controlled
>     positive-feedback**, making it behave with hysteresis (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis).

I found some interesting notes on basic comparator circuits, fairly well written and explained,

http://www.hbcc.edu.sa/facpages/syedmuhammadasad/data_files/eeet%20201/ch13.pdf